# Hibernate exception class is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate

Hey i am new to hibernate and java and im getting this exception i tried multiple solutions i found on google and nothing seems to work. Would appreciate any help. I am trying to return number of rows from table in database.

I am using mapping in xml file and im using addAnnotatedClass yet it is still throwing exception.

Here is my code:

Main.java

```
package springfoxdemo.java.swagger;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class Main {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    Session session = null;
    try
    {
        try
        {
            Configuration cfg= new Configuration().addAnnotatedClass(Polica.class);
            cfg.configure();
            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        catch(Throwable th)
        {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object."
            + th);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);
        }
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        
        Query query = session.createQuery("select count(p) from Polica p");
        Iterator count = query.iterate();
        System.out.println("No. of rows : "+ count.next()); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        session.close();
    }
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">PASS</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">DBCONNECTION</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">USERNAME</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        
        <mapping class="springfoxdemo.java.swagger.Polica"/>
    </session-factory>
    
    
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Polica.java

```
package springfoxdemo.java.swagger;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
public class Polica {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="ime_pol")
    private String ime_pol;
    
    public Polica() {
        super();
    }
    
    public Polica(int id, String ime_pol) {
        this.id = id;
        this.ime_pol = ime_pol;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getIme_pol() {
        return ime_pol;
    }
    public void setIme_pol(String ime_pol) {
        this.ime_pol = ime_pol;
    }
    
}
```

Exception:

```
Polica is not mapped [select count(p) from Polica p]
```

Comment: Check your select request. 
Maybe you need use 'select count(*) from Polica'

Comment: Tried it and it sadly doesn't work.

Comment: `cfg.configure()` uses the XML file for configuration. I think it could overwrite whatever was configured before. So `addAnnotatedClass(Polica.class)` is ignored. I am not sure about XML configuration, but from what I read, you need to define mapping in there as well.